# C++17 Iterate over a subset of parameter pack

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I have a struct receiving a parameter pack. Let's assume that the parameter pack will never have a size smaller than 3. Also, the `std::array` found in the struct should be evaluated at compile-time. I want to fill the array using the parameter pack, but I want to skip the first and the last element.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template<int32_t ...Ts>
struct St {
    const std::array<int32_t, sizeof...(Ts)-2U> arr{};
};

int main() {
    constexpr St<7, 2, 1, 5, 6> s;
    std::cout << s.arr[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use a `std::index_sequence` with elements from [1, sizeof_parameter_pack - 1] or [0, size_of_parameter_pack - 2] and a fold expression to fill the array. However, I'm struggling with creating the index_sequence. I don't want the struct to receive another template parameter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I might have missunderstood something, but I think that the `arr` should be const since there will be more objects of the same struct

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution with `std::index_sequence`:

```
template<int32_t... Ts>
struct St {
    static constexpr auto Size = sizeof...(Ts) - 2;
    const std::array<int32_t, Size> arr;

    constexpr St() : St(std::array{Ts...}, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}) {}

private:
    template<class Arr, std::size_t... I>
    constexpr St(Arr init, std::index_sequence<is...>) : arr{init[I + 1]...} {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is doing the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template<uint32_t... Ts>
constexpr std::array<int32_t, sizeof...(Ts)-1> create_arr() {
    const std::array<int32_t, sizeof...(Ts)> tmp{Ts...};
    std::array<int32_t, sizeof...(Ts)-1> ret{};
    // With C++20, this is a call to std::copy
    for(auto i = 0ul; i != tmp.size()-1; ++i) {
        ret[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
template<uint32_t first, uint32_t ...Ts>
struct St {
    const std::array<int32_t, sizeof...(Ts)-1> arr = create_arr<Ts...>();
};

int main() {
    constexpr St<7U, 2U, 1U, 5U, 6U> s;
    std::cout << s.arr[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This can be evaluated at run-time (if your `St` object is not `constexpr`), you can get around that by declaring the array-member `constexpr`.

Btw: Are you sure, that you want to initialize the `int32_t` array from `uint32_t`?

Comment: I replaced the uint32_t for the int32_t, thanks for the note!